# Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression Importing npm module

Tags: vue.js

I have read tons of questions and it seems to be a webpack issue but I can't realize how to solve it. I have installed [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mercadopago) npm module and when I attempt to import it I got the dependency error.
The imported file (`var mercadopago = require('mercadopago');`) contains only the following line:

```
module.exports = require('./lib/mercadopago.js');
```

I'm using Vue and webpack version is 4.42.1. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a NodeJS SDK. Which means it won't work in the browser. It would however work if you import it in your NodeJS Server.

Comment: It is triggered from a form, so to test it out I'll have no other choice than in a production environment? (there you have the usage explained: https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/en/guides/payments/web-payment-checkout/integration/#editor_1592492894)

Comment: You don't require a production environment to test it out. You just need an api server that handles the request. If you happen to write it with nodejs you could just take their [example](https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/en/guides/payments/web-payment-checkout/integration/#editor_1592491200) here.